# Is there any single word in English to represent domain of "logic and science" together?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, science, logic

Is there any single word in English to represent domain of "logic and science" together?

#### Background

Some of my friends are going to start an online movement whose main purpose would be creating awareness on "science and logic" to the common people. They need a name for the movement, like "feminist movement", "secular movement" etc.

Comment: Those are already very vague words. A word that represented both of them would be even vaguer.

Comment: @JohnLawler you meant 'abstract' ? why would we call them vague?

Comment: Because everybody has their own definitions of them, and they don't agree. Rather like saying "tasty"; they're all opinion.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Thanks. In that case, I rather like Laurel's suggestion above "STEM". See https://www.stem.org.uk/stem-clubs

Comment: @Greybeard its close but not exactly what I am looking for. The actual purpose is a little different, basically the movement is to remove dogmatic superstitions of common people which mainly dependent on "scientific and logical" understandings. Engineering and Technology are optional here. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the conjunction of two words? While *STEM* is indeed relevant, if you're trying to express the idea to "the common people," simply using "science and logic" (or "scientific and logical" if you need adjectives)  would be the most understandable. Otherwise, you fall into the trap of using jargon or a buzz word to describe something that's meant to be understood in plain language.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109040/discussion-on-question-by-sazzad-hissain-khan-is-there-any-single-word-in-englis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the *domain of science and logic* **rationality** or **reason**. From Lexico:

> **[rationality](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rationality)**: The quality of being based on or in accordance with reason or logic.
>
> **[reason](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/reason)**: The power of the mind to think, understand, and form judgments by a process of logic.

Your friends could lead the "**rationality** movement", the "**reason** movement", the "**let's be reasonable** movement", or maybe the "**Can we talk?**" movement.

Another possibility is **enlightenment**. From Lexido:

> **[enlightenment](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enlightenment)**: The action of enlightening or the state of being enlightened.
>
> **[the Enlightenment](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enlightenment)**: A European intellectual movement of the late 17th and 18th centuries emphasizing reason and individualism rather than tradition.

Yes, **the Enlightenment** has already been used, but your friends could call their movement **The New Enlightenment**.

Comment: How about “Rationalist Movement”?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Sounds good given that rationalists are advocates of rationalism. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The proper term to use is *Evidence Based*. Join the *Evidence Based* movement!

The practice of Logic is based on known, largely agreed upon mathematical rules. These go from the syntactic to the semantic but I'm sure there is a modern host of variations and embattled subtleties. The distinction it enjoys is that there *are* rules.

Science is a bit more subjective, deal with it. The practice is to offer explanations of observed data. These are couched within the context of an hypothesis and a conclusion or results based on how well the hypothesis fits the observed facts, the evidence. Comments are bound to correct me. I truly dread to point it out but these steps do become subjective since it is up to what one wishes to observe and what one most expects to see. The subjectivity is meant to be rinsed away by the careful practice of double blind, mature, earnest record keeping. It is not easily done nowadays.

Since math and chemistry and physics have become mere starting points for modern science we like to think of science as being as accurate as these. In my opinion once you leave them behind science loses correspondingly more credibility. If you study what happened to string theory [see *Not Even Wrong*, or *The Trouble With Physics*] you will find that even physics has yielded to the most subjective and passion based waves of fashion. Once scientific results motivate political discussion the game is truly up.

I can well imagine that the well intentioned goal of this movement will be to lead, direct or embarrass non-members into accepting a set of facts that make the members feel right and justified. Good for them. They know what they want and should certainly have it. This is a long way of strongly recommending that you must use ***Neither*** *Science* or *Logic* your title.

Instead the proper term to use is ***Evidence Based***. Here the quality of the observation is open to consideration by all, not only to the scientist observing. And the conclusions are also open to the more than just the members interpretation, not as the final product of the institution whose survival depends on the results to maintain its budget or else just hang it up.

Others tell me it is not up to Josephine six-pack to understand why a certain Chi-Square distribution is or is not appropriate for a given set of data. I agree, somewhat. My reasons of why and why not belong in the comments. Here I have answered the question and explained why it fits.

Comment: Science is evidence and reason. Evidence comes first, however, so *evidence-based* is appropriate here.